# Find databases with no recent activity

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Is there some SQL that I can use in order to find out which databases on the Server haven't been used recently?  I need to find the ones that are no longer used and detach them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if a SQL Server database is still being used?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/how-can-i-tell-if-a-sql-server-database-is-still-being-used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can gather some info from the index usage stats DMV (unless your databases are full of tables sans indexes). Aaron Bertrand has an article here which might be of interest to you: http://goo.gl/twAlh

Comment: good idea. I clean forgot about that

Answer (score 2):

No, unless you

- logged access in your tables
- had a trace (SQL Profiler) running
- have a logon trigger
- ...

You have to explicitly monitor this somehow.

If you need to do it *now*, you could make the database single user and see who calls...

Comment: Thanks - I guess SQL doesn't track when a database was last used.

Comment: Take @yogirk's answer, subject to provisos in the linked article