# How to find if the application uses the database snapshots in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm taking over dba responsibilities for the migration of an environment that the application owners are unable to give enough information on.

I need to comment on possibility of optimizing licensing cost. Having compared Enterprise and Standard edition features, the only concerns i have are for Database snapshots and TDE, both of which are only supported by Enterprise in SQL 2012.

There are snapshots in SSMS for some of the databases, but how do I know if the application is using them or not? My thoughts are that, if they are not being used then we could look at using Standard edition.

For TDE I can check that with sys.dm_database_encryption_keys.

Any thoughts to guide me will be appreciated please.

Thank you

Comment: Some of the answers here should be viable options for you: [How can I tell if a SQL Server database is still being used?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/how-can-i-tell-if-a-sql-server-database-is-still-being-used)

Comment: @LowlyDBA-JohnM, thanks for your response. It isn't the use of the database itself I'm concerned about, it is rather the use of the database snapshots in SSMS. The read-only snapshots. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

Sql server 2012 will go out of support next year July 2022.

For more recent sql server edition key points are HA & DR features like AG.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15?view=sql-server-ver15

Other good point are the index online rebuild feature, but also memory limit, read-ahead, partitions and data compression.

Comment: thanks for your response, that's helpful. Unfortunately at this point in time, we have to work with SQL 2012. Thanks again, all the same.